# Is there an extension or add-in for VS to extend a partial class?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

This seems like something that might be in some extension out there somewhere. I'd just like to know where I can find it or similar functionality.

**Instead of:**

1. create new class with same name same as partial class (most likely generated)
2. type "public partial" in front of the name
3. add a method

**Something more like:**

1. right click on class in object browser
2. select "Extend this partial class..."
3. add a method

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution 1: Item Template

While not as good as an Object Browser plugin, you may get some benefit from an item template for partial classes. Using an item template you can add a partial class definition from the Add New Item dialog just as you would a standard class definition.

The template creates a file equivilant to

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Project1
{
    partial class PartialClass1
    {
    }
}
```

The template I created is available [here](https://skydrive.live.com/embed?cid=4E3C5B7D5630665F&resid=4E3C5B7D5630665F!146&authkey=ACF7I4phK2GQkyI).

In order for it to appear in the Visual Studio 2010 Add New Items dialog one needs to place the zip file[1](https://skydrive.live.com/embed?cid=4E3C5B7D5630665F&resid=4E3C5B7D5630665F!146&authkey=ACF7I4phK2GQkyI) in the `%userprofile%\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Templates\ItemTemplates` subdirectory and then restart Visual Studio.

If you've done this correctly you should see an additonal item in your Add New Items dialog box:

[image: When the template is installed successfully, the Partial Class template will appear in the Add New Item dialog]

Notes:

1. You must place the zip file itself in this location rather than extracting the zip file's contents here.
2. When I exported te template from Visual Studio it also appeared in the ``%userprofile%\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\My Exported Templates` folder. I suspect this is purely because I created it, but I thought I'd include it for completeness in case it actually is a requirement.
3. The template I created does not include the public modifier by default, but one could simply edit PartialClass.cs in the zip file to add it if desired.

#### Solution 2: Code Snippet

After I created the template, I felt annoyed that one still had to manually type a class name. A code snippet solves this problem by allowing you to replace the class name with the help of the Visual Studio editor.

I've created a code snippet to insert partial classes. It's available [here](https://skydrive.live.com/embed?cid=4E3C5B7D5630665F&resid=4E3C5B7D5630665F!148&authkey=AAgrozjMt4eW9NY).

Once downloaded it must be installed by opening the Code Snippet Manager from the Tools menu in Visual Studio, choosing Import and then browsing to the `partialclass.snippet file.

Once the snippet has been installed a partial class can be inserted by typing `pcl` and pressing the TAB key twice. Visual Studio will expand the snippet and provide assistance to edit both the access modifier and the class name.

Notes:

1. SkyDrive seems to have truncated the extension of the `partialclass.snippet` file. You might need to add the `.snippet` extension after downloading.

Comment: After creating the template, I realized the editing help you get from a code snippet would help here, so I made one.